World orientation with Geometric Nodes
Good afternoon. As a tutorial, I'm making a simple system for procedurally creating handrails. As long as the railings are on the same plane (1), everything is fine. But when bending, the vertical elements are oriented locally (2). How to make sure that they are always, at any tilt, straight up, according to world coordinates?
Additional info -
In the railings, all their parts (upper profile, lower profile, two intermediate ones, balusters) are separate objects that I can change. They are customizable according to the distance between them, and different types of profiles. And everything works - except that the balusters are not oriented according to the world coordinate system when the bend goes along the Z axis. Here is the frame that controls the balusters -

Thank you.

update:
what about just unplugging rotation? does that help?



unfortunately you didn't really specify how your handrails should look like. But if you really "just" want to make the point on z axis, you could use this node setup:

if you wanna have same y-distance, you could use this setup:


Thanks for the answer. Yes, unfortunately, I gave incomplete information. I added some info in original post ( its my first post here and i don't know how to add images to comment)

i updated my answer. if this still doesn't help, please provide your blend file. thx.

you can add images in comments by first starting a new answer, copy the image in there, then copy the generated link and cancel that answer. Then you can copy that link in the comment.

For 'same y disdtance'.. . (same xy distance?)...  simpler to achieve by scaling curve to 0 in Z, resampling while flat, stashing XY and combining with existing Z ?

@RobinBetts: that's actually an easier way!

Thank you, it solved, solution was in your first example. I can add all other functionality based on your basic. Thank you!
